# Calcular diferencia entre dos fechas PHP

Tags: php, diff

Quiero saber la diferencia en días entre dos fechas dadas en el formato:

```
2018/01/05
```

**Código PHP:**

```
$diferencia_dias = $check_in->diff($check_out);
echo $diferencia_dias->format('%R%a días');
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 3):

La forma de hacerlo es lo siguiente: 
*Fuente: Documentación PHP*

```
<?php
    $fecha1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
    $fecha2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
    $resultado = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
    echo $resultado->format('%R%a días');
?>
```

Comment: Si te fijas, el detalle esta en el formato de entrada, que usa `/` en lugar de `-`